# WCF Service Error on generate code file with SVCUtil

Tags: wcf, mono, svcutil.exe

I created a WCF service with  net framework 4.0 on Windows OS; 
and its works OK use SVCUtil to generate client code file.
but its failed on ubuntu apache with mono.
error info below:

```
exception :System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerMessageContractImporter

details:
Due to the namespace "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System" with data
contract name "MarshalByRefObject" reference types "System. MarshalByRefObject, 
mscorlib, VerSion = 4.0.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = b77a5c561934e089 "
 with import DataConTract does not match, so can't use. you need to remove the 
type of the reference.
```

but how can i remove the  type of the reference MarshalByRefObject on mono?

Any assistance would be appreciated. Thanks a bunch for your help.